# Multiple INSERT with same column (MS ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to append from table like this (DesignID, ink1, ink2, ink3, mesh1, mesh2, mesh3) to the new table (ID, DesignID, ink, mesh) in order to reduce repeating values... I'm quite new to to SQL and couldn't find an answer... I'm trying to figure out how I would do this in one query instead of running in 3 times...

So far I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Ink ( DesignID, Mesh, Ink )
    SELECT Design.DesignID, Design.Mesh1, Design.Ink1
    FROM Design
    WHERE (((Design.Ink1) Is Not Null))

    UNION ALL

INSERT INTO Ink ( DesignID, Mesh, Ink )
    SELECT Design.DesignID, Design.Mesh2, Design.Ink2
    FROM Design
    WHERE (((Design.Ink2) Is Not Null));

UNION ALL

INSERT INTO Ink ( DesignID, Mesh, Ink )
    SELECT Design.DesignID, Design.Mesh3, Design.Ink3
    FROM Design
    WHERE (((Design.Ink3) Is Not Null));
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear for someone who is looking for the answer. Here is the correct query. As @Lee_Mac stated plus a little add:

```
INSERT INTO Ink ( DesignID, Mesh, Ink )
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DesignID, Mesh1 as Mesh, Ink1 as Ink
FROM Design
WHERE Ink1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DesignID, Mesh2, Ink2
FROM Design
WHERE Ink2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DesignID, Mesh3, Ink3
FROM Design
WHERE Ink3 IS NOT NULL
)
```

This will work and run with no problems. First SELECT should be selected as names of the fields you are inserting in to in order to run and work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `SELECT ... INTO` with a union of the two selects:

```
SELECT t.* INTO Ink
FROM
(
    SELECT DesignID, Mesh1, Ink1
    FROM Design
    WHERE Ink1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DesignID, Mesh2, Ink2
    FROM Design
    WHERE Ink2 IS NOT NULL
) t;
```

Comment: I get "syntax error (missing operator) query expression 'Ink1 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL SELECT DesignID, Mesh2, Ink2
FROM Design
WHERE Ink2 IS NOT NULL;

Comment: @StanV I updated my answer, please try this version.

Comment: This worked! Access working in a strange ways! Thank you for looking in to it for me!

Answer (score 1):

A `SELECT ... INTO` statement will delete & recreate the destination table when executed, which may not be desired behaviour based on the `INSERT INTO` statements used in the question.

To avoid three separate `INSERT INTO` statements, I would suggest a single `INSERT INTO` statement which sources data from three unioned `SELECT` queries:

```
INSERT INTO Ink ( DesignID, Mesh, Ink )
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DesignID, Mesh1, Ink1
    FROM Design
    WHERE Ink1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DesignID, Mesh2, Ink2
    FROM Design
    WHERE Ink2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DesignID, Mesh3, Ink3
    FROM Design
    WHERE Ink3 IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Actually while I can use VIEW I cannot run it :-/ I get this error: The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name 'Mesh1'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly and try operation again...

Comment: Got the fix for it in first select statement: SELECT DesignID, Mesh1 as Mesh, Ink1 as Ink. This will make it run

Comment: @StanV I'm surprised you needed to do this.  In most versions of SQL, it wouldn't be necessary.